# Count all rows in array where a specific field is set (not empty)

Tags: php, arrays, count

I wish to count how many rows in an array has a certain field set to some value (not `Null`).

Something like: `count(isset($names->array_value))`.

Is there a command in php for this?

Comment: Put it through a loop and put each name as the index/key and count++ their values. Oh! You might need to check if the index exists before hand - been a while since I worked with php.

Comment: Isn't there any shorter command in php for this purpose? Or is a loop the only method?

Comment: I could use `array_keys`, yes, but since I don't know the search term (it is different for all the fields) I have to look for any non-set values. Something like: `count(array_keys($members,'NULL'))`. I can't search for the NULL in this manner though, but what is the right method?

Comment: Well those functions/commands are typically just basic statements like loops n such. The array will have to be iterated through regardless of if you see the code or not.

Comment: @Steeven Well since your check is (even a little bit) more complicated than *check if it's true*, you will need a spec. function for checking if your condition are met or not... and that's the point where you realize that simple loop is... well... more simple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can check with this code:

```
if (isset($names['array_value']) && is_array($names['array_value'])){
    echo count($names['array_value']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_filter()` and count the result, but since you'll have to write special function for it, simple `foreach` loop seems like best option to me.